# Find conditional of two normally distributed variables

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution

Given two independent random variables (which describe two workers' durations to complete a task) $t_1, t_2$ which are normally distributed with ($\mu_1=20,\sigma_1=5$) and ($\mu_2=30,\sigma_2=10$). A task is given at random to worker 1 or 2 with equal probability of $p=0.5$.

A task is completed in $t=10$. Now, I would like to find the probability of this task being completed by worker 2.

It would be great if someone could guide me through this task.
So far I came up with the following thought-process:

1) I assume workers durations to be independent, thus
$p(t)=p(t_1)p(t_2)$ (But not  sure what to do with the equal probability of 0.5)

2) My goal is to find $p(\text{worker}_2\vert t=10)$ but I am not sure how?

Ideas I had:

- Use $p(t)=\mathcal{N}(\mu_1+\mu_2,\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2 )$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74581/discussion-between-duffau-and-oliver).

Answer (score 0):

There are two type of workers, $W = 1$ and $W=2$. Given an observation of completion time $t$, we can use Bayes' rule to compute the probability that this observation was produced by a worker of type $i$:
\begin{equation}
p(W=i|t) = \frac{p(t|W=i)\,p(W=i)}{p(t)} ,
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
p(t) = \sum_{i=1}^2 p(t|W=i)\,p(W=i) . 
\end{equation}

In the setup we are told $p(W=1) = p(W=2) = 1/2$, $p(t|W=1) = \textsf{N}(t|20,5^2)$, and $p(t|W=2) = \textsf{N}(t|30,10^2)$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
p(W=2|t=10) = \frac{\textsf{N}(10|30,10^2)\times \frac{1}{2}}{\textsf{N}(10|20,5^2)\times \frac{1}{2} + \textsf{N}(10|30,10^2)\times \frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{3} . 
\end{equation}

Comment: My teacher always tells us that the normal distribution is zero for a single value (e.g. like here t=10) - why does this not apply here?

Comment: The probability of a single value is indeed zero. But the density at a single value is not zero. The answer involves the densities of a single value for two different distributions.

Comment: It is confusing, then, to call these quantities "probabilities" in your answer and then claim in a comment that they are "densities."  In fact, *some* of them are probabilities and *some* of them are densities!